# Multiplying Columns by Scalars in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns named 'A' and 'B'.

Now suppose I also have a dictionary with keys 'A' and 'B', and the dictionary points to a scalar. That is, dict['A'] = 1.2 and similarly for 'B'.

Is there a simple way to multiply each column of the DataFrame by these scalars?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Wouter said, the recommended method is to convert the dict to a pandas.Series and multiple the two objects together:

`result = df * pd.Series(myDict)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
for col in df.columns:
     df[col] *= myDict[col]
```

Comment: Can't be more elegant than that. Thank you.

Comment: df * pd.series(d) is ok too.